# Power automate: Save/Get inline image that uses XML/vml/omml in the body?

Tags: xml, office365, power-automate, vml, omml

I have an email that comes in with the following snippet from the body....

```
<body lang=EN-GB link="#5563C1" vlink="#454F72" style='word-wrap:break-word'>
   <div class=WordSection1>
  <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:12.0pt;text-align:center'>
     <span lang=EN style='font-size:7.5pt'><img width=1200 height=900 style='width:13.4062in;height:9.4375in' id="Picture_x0120_2" src="cid:EmailContent.png"></span>
     <span lang=EN style='font-size:7.5pt'>
        <o:p></o:p>
     </span>
  </p>
  <p class=MsoNormal>
     <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
  </p>
```

It uses

```
src="cid:EmailContent.png"
```

Now I can view and save as image in Outlook, when I pass that in Power automate to get or view the image, it breaks.  How would I save the image or create a file in sharepoint?

Comment: You can find such images in the attachments collection

Comment: I have this in the outputs, but how do I tell Power automate to create a file or even access this data?   {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
    "id": "AAMkADJhZjljHJHJudUP05ZGEzLWFkMDg4YWRkYzExYwBGAAAAAAA4skaa1bq2RK_fkKvbwIUGBwBkZs3ejIbrQJDlSnsy2GYHAAAAAAEMAABJYEI0ZvqNSLGXkfOp3_SiAAAPhfSXAAABEgAQAB8o1nZ0mqZCtpyz9GBHyrA=",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-01-31T16:31:21+00:00",
    "name": "EmailContent.png",
    "contentType": "image/png",
    "size": 80583,
    "isInline": true
}